# If f is integrable on an interval [a,a+T] of length T,then prove that f is also integrable on any other interval [b,b+T] of length T.

Tags: periodic-functions

If I can show that the function is integrable on any other interval of length T,I can certainly show that the integration values of that function over these two different intervals of same length are equal. That part is pretty easy. How to show that f is integrable on any other interval of same length?

Comment: Don't you see anything wrong with the question from the title? Besides, what has this to do with `fourier-series`?

Comment: Yeah I can change the Tag...but the question is completely okay.

Comment: The question is as if you were asking: If $A$ is a set of real numbers and if every $B\subset A$ is bounded, then prove that every $C\subset A$ is bounded.

Comment: No...my question isn't indicating that. I said "If f is integrable on any interval [a,a+T]..."...here it doesn't mean that f is integrable on any interval of length T...yeah I'm choosing one interval arbitrarily...but once I've chosen one interval,it is fixed...like this interval should be a concrete one and given in the question.

Comment: Okay...for convenience,I've made a change to my question. I think now my question is understandable!

Comment: My guess is that you also forgot to mention that $T$ is a period of $f$.